# Putting a n labeled balls into k urns with constraints

Tags: mathematical-optimization, counting

I am trying to find a solution to a problem of putting n balls belonging to distinct classes into k bins, with the constraint is that each bin has c number of balls. We can assume that the number of balls n can be divided by the number of bins k.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: I am not writing a code for it at the moment.
My overall problem is to find a lower bound of the average statistical distance (earth mover distance) between the distribution inside each bin and the overall distribution.

Comment: Is the question "how many distinct ways are there to put n balls ..."?   I think it's something like C(n,c) * C(n-c,c) * ... * C(c,c) .

Comment: The question: is how many ways are there to put n balls with labels on them into urns of fixed size?
As an example, with 2 urns and 4 balls (two of them belonging to class 1 and two of them belonging to class 2), the ways to partition is [{1,1},{2,2}], [{1,2}, {1,2}] and [{2,2}, {1,1}]

Comment: "two of them belonging to class 2"?   I thought the balls were distinct, which I interpreted to mean that all the classes have one member each.

Comment: Yes, the balls are labeled into fixed number of classes

Comment: In that case, take my formula involving combinations -- C(n,k) -- and divide the result by the product of the factorials of the class sizes.

Comment: Can you provide intuitive explanation of your formula?

Comment: OK, first, let's assume that all the balls are distinctly labeled, then come back later and fix that assumption.   I also assume that the bins are distinctly labeled, too, although you didn't say either way on that.   So, to fill the first bin, you have to choose "c" balls out of "n",or C(n,c) -- the number of combinations of n things taken c at a time.   Next, fill the second bin from the remaining n-c balls, or C(n-c,c).   Keep doing this until we get to C(c,c), which is 1.  Next account for the fact that the balls are not distinct.   Let's say we have one class "i" that has "q" balls...

Comment: ...then, to account for the fact that "q" balls are indistinguishable, divide by the number of permutations of "q" things, or factorial(q).   Finally, since we may have many classes with multiple members, divide by the product of the factorials of all class sizes.   Make any more sense?